# Select rows where two values conform to a certain threshold

Tags: r

I am using R and I need to select the rows where any value is > 0.7 and any other value < 0.4.
Two values should meet this requirement. If there is another value in the row that does not apply to this I still want to take this row.

Df:

```
    A   B   C   D   E
1   NA  0.5 0.6 NA  NA
2   NA  0.2 0.8 NA  NA
3   NA  0.2 NA  0.6 NA
4   NA  0.6 0.1 0.8 NA
```

The output should look like this:

```
    A   B   C   D   E
2   NA  0.2 0.8 NA  NA
4   NA  0.6 0.1 0.8 NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try (thanks to @akrun for the edit suggestion)

```
df[!!rowSums(df > .7, na.rm = TRUE) & !!rowSums(df < 0.4, na.rm = TRUE), ]
##    A   B   C   D  E
## 2 NA 0.2 0.8  NA NA
## 4 NA 0.6 0.1 0.8 NA
```

Or (worse option)

```
df[apply(df, 1, function(x) any(x > .7, na.rm = TRUE) & any(x < .4, na.rm = TRUE)), ]
#    A   B   C   D  E
# 2 NA 0.2 0.8  NA NA
# 4 NA 0.6 0.1 0.8 NA
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
Df is indeed my dataframe, sorry I'm so unclear. 
Unfortunately this solution still takes the rows that only have >.7 or <.4, not rows that have both. (Maybe because of my bad explanation, sorry again!)

I tried this with & instead of |, but this gives no output at all..

Answer (score 1):

You could also try:

```
 Df[intersect(which(Df >0.7, arr.ind=TRUE)[,1] , which(Df <0.4,arr.ind=TRUE)[,1]),]
 #     A   B   C   D  E
 #2 NA 0.2 0.8  NA NA
 #4 NA 0.6 0.1 0.8 NA
```

#### data

```
 Df <- structure(list(A = c(NA, NA, NA, NA), B = c(0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 0.6
 ), C = c(0.6, 0.8, NA, 0.1), D = c(NA, NA, 0.6, 0.8), E = c(NA, 
 NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
 "2", "3", "4"))
```